# Jquery Function for skipping to a textbox on keypress

Tags: asp.net, jquery, function

I currently have 4 textboxes which will be used to store an ip address.
What i need help with is a function that will allow a user to input a "." and have the textbox change focus from the current textbox to the next textbox.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd suggest not to use separate textboxes - you won't be able to copy & paste the address. That can get annoying...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your textboxes are named ip0, ip1, ip2, ip3:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#ip0,#ip1,#ip2').keydown( function(event) {
       var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode || 0;
       if (key == 190) {
           event.preventDefault();
           var i = Number(this.id.replace(/ip/,'')) +1;
           $('#ip'+i).focus();
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson!
This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
textbox.onChange = function(){
   if(textbox.value[textbox.value.length-1] =='.'){
     textbox.value = textbox.value.substring(0,textbox.value.length-2);
     nextTextbox.focus();
   }
}
```

I didn't test this but I think something in this general idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use a "mask"-plugin, like this one: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
That would give you the opportunity to give it a nice look and still let your visitors copy an IP and pasting it.

Comment: +1 from me - I have never worked out who's supposed to be helped by most of the overcomplicated methods of entering IP addresess.

Comment: i don't know if that will work with an ip address though, since each octet can vary from 1 to 3 integers.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you catch the onKeyPress event on the box and if the char is matches a "." focus on the next box? For example:

```
var dotCode = ".".charCodeAt( 0 );
$("box0").bind( "keypress", function( e ){ 
    if( e.keyCode === dotCode ){ $("box1").focus( ); }
});

// etc...
```